# Microsoft SQL Server: Query to see list of all databases, and their corresponding tables, and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I have found seems to only show this for one database at a time (e.g., select * from information_schema.columns). Is there something like select * from sys.databases which includes not just all of the database names, but also their own table and column names?

Would like to see all of these for the server: database names, table names, column names.

I'm trying to get familiar with a server at a new company, and want to just explore by browsing the table names and columns in every database. Also, **I do not have write access**, and am doing this in Tableau custom SQL.

Comment: You can use the undocumented sp_msforeachdb but it will sometimes skip databases. You could also leverage dynamic sql for this which is probably what I would do. What are you wanting for output? Just databasename, tablename and columnname?

Comment: The only way to do something like that is via dynamic sql. What is your real goal here? Why do you want to do this? What is it you think you need?  Maybe you're asking the wrong question, because I can't imagine what value this really is... it's too generic and broad.  can you focus your question to your specific need?

Comment: Yes, just need those three things. I'm trying to get familiar with a server at a new company, and want to just explore by browsing the table names and columns in every database. Also, I do not have write access, and am doing this in Tableau custom SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this? You can try msforeachdb

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb N'
BEGIN
    use ?
    select * from information_schema.tables
    select * from information_schema.columns
END';
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a big fan of undocumented procedures. And sp_msforeachdb will sometimes skip databases and nobody really seem to know why. Aaron Bertrand wrote alternatives here:

- [Making a more reliable and flexible sp_MSforeachdb](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/)
- [Execute a Command in the Context of Each Database in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5694/execute-a-command-in-the-context-of-each-database-in-sql-server--part-2/)

I also really don't care for cursors which is all that undocumented procedure is. If you look at the code it is one big ugly cursor. For something as simple as you desire I prefer to use some dynamic sql and sys tables to create it.

Here is how I would go about this task. It really isn't much more code than undocumented procedure. The big advantage is that is a LOT simpler to debug and there is no cursor. :)

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select @SQL = @SQL + 'select ''' + d.name + ''' as DatabaseName 
    , t.name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as TableName
    , c.name collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS as ColumnName
from ' + quotename(d.name) + '.sys.tables t 
join ' + quotename(d.name) + '.sys.columns c on c.object_id = t.object_id UNION ALL '
from sys.databases d

set @SQL = LEFT(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10) + ' order by DatabaseName, TableName, ColumnName'

select @SQL --once you are satisfied the sql is correct just uncomment the line below
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

One I've used before:

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_MSForEachDB N'
    IF ''?'' NOT IN (''master'', ''model'', ''msdb'', ''tempdb'')   
    BEGIN
    USE ? 
    SELECT ''?'' AS theDatabase
        , OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([tables].[object_id],DB_ID()) AS theSchema
        , [tables].name AS theTable
        , [columns].[name] AS theColumn
        , [types].[name] AS theDatatype
        , [columns].max_length AS columnSize
        , [columns].[precision] AS columnPrecision
        , [columns].scale AS columnScale
        , [columns].is_nullable AS isNullable
    FROM sys.tables AS [tables]
    INNER JOIN sys.all_columns [columns] ON [tables].[object_id] = [columns].[object_id]  
    INNER JOIN sys.types [types] ON [columns].system_type_id = [types].system_type_id
        AND [columns].user_type_id = [types].user_type_id
    WHERE [tables].is_ms_shipped = 0  
    ORDER BY [tables].name, [columns].column_id
    END
'
```

I usually dump it into a temp table so I can better manipulate the resulting data.

I haven't run into the issue with sp_MSforEachDB missing tables, but I'll check out Aaron's article about the issue. He's definitely a name I trust. :-)

Answer (score -3):

Yo, maybe try this?

--Database Names

SELECT name
FROM sys.databases

--Table Names

SELECT name
FROM sys.tables

--Column Names

SELECT name
FROM sys.columns

That help?

Comment: Sorry, that just gives you the names. You can also use * if you want more than that.

Comment: The OP wants this information for ALL databases on the server, not just for the current one.