# TSQL Cross Apply determining which databases to query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, cross-apply, cross-database

I'm writing (in .NET) a login screen that allows the login to connect to a SQL Server. Once they've put in the server name and their credentials, it should then show a list of databases for them to connect to, but, the databases need to be of the right structure. This will be identified within each database by the existence of a `ref.Config` table, and a row in that table with appropriate values. There may be a whole bunch of other databases on the server for other purposes. I don't know at designtime.

Ideally what I'd like to do is something like this:

```
SELECT  m.name
FROM    MASTER.sys.databases m
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM    {m.name}.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
                    WHERE   t.TABLE_SCHEMA = 'ref'
                    AND     t.TABLE_NAME 'Config') dbs
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                    FROM    {m.name}.ref.Config c
                    WHERE   c.KeyName = 'DatabaseMagicNumber'
                    AND     c.KeyValue = '12345678') config
WHERE   HAS_DBACCESS(m.name) = 1
ORDER BY m.name
```

Where `m.name` gets substituted into the subqueries after evaluation (I know the above isn't valid SQL). Is there a way to do this, or do I have to run a query on each database? I am unable to have a stored procedure on the server at this point. Ideally I just want one SQL statement that will return the names of all databases that conform to the structure I expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all tables in all databases in SQL Server in a single result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2875768/how-do-i-list-all-tables-in-all-databases-in-sql-server-in-a-single-result-set)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft SQL Server: Query to see list of all databases, and their corresponding tables, and columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43945327/11683)

Comment: Yes, I think that's a goer - thank you. Getting a collation error in it (I've used a different collation in one database for testing with collation), but I can resolve that. Thank you.

Comment: Careful - use of [information_schema.tables.table_schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/tables-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is discouraged

Comment: I'd also make sure you are very careful about protecting against SQL injection since it seems like you are planning to go the dynamic SQL route.